# Laravel check if related model (A better solution?)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a app that shows flights. In the fligh selection workflow the user should first pick a destination. In my "pick a destination view" I display all the Countries in my database. Some of them haven't flights. I'm attempting to show just the countries with flights, to accomplish that, I've written this method:

```
public function getDestinationsWithFlights()
    {
        $destinations = Destination::all();
        $destinationsWithFlights = [];

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($destinations) ; $i++)
        {
            if ($destinations[$i]->hasMany(Flight::class)->count() != 0)
            {
                $destinationsWithFlights[$i] = $destinations[$i];
            }
        }

        return $destinationsWithFlights;
    }
```

the response is

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": 1,
        "country": "argentina",
        "created_at": "2016-08-03 13:56:36",
        "updated_at": "2016-08-03 13:56:36"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 3,
        "country": "spain",
        "created_at": "2016-08-03 13:56:36",
        "updated_at": "2016-08-03 13:56:36"
    }
}
```

I don't know where these keys, "0" and "2", came from. And I think there most be a better solution to that. And, also, I'd prefer the response to be something like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "country": "argentina",
    "created_at": "2016-08-03 13:56:36",
    "updated_at": "2016-08-03 13:56:36"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "country": "spain",
    "created_at": "2016-08-03 13:56:36",
    "updated_at": "2016-08-03 13:56:36"
}
```

You guys have any idea? Or you think it's fine the way I did it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `flights` relationship to your `Destination` model:

```
public function flights()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Flight::class);
}
```

Then query only `destinations` with `flights` like:

```
$destinations = Destination::has('flights')->get();
```

Your `getDestinationsWithFlights` function should look something like:

```
public function getDestinationsWithFlights()
{
    return Destination::has('flights')->get()->toArray();
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. I already had the relation set up but I didn't know you could add that has method to the query. Thanks! A lot!